# Ignore/ remove error message while opening .xlsx file through code

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-4

In my asp.net, MVC application we are generating and downloading .xlsx file. But when I am trying to open, it's giving a message

"The file you are trying to open, 'filename.xlsx', is in a different format than specified by the file extension. Verify that the file is not corrupted and is from a trusted source before opening the file. Do you want to open the file now?"
If I press 'Yes' it's opening. I changed the file extension to .xls, still same message. Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I've added .xlsx & .xls MIME type extension in IIS manager with MIME Type as application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet. Still it's showing the same message. Please suggest how can I get rid off it.

Please find my existing code lines for the same -

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
   // Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Survey Report.xlsx");

It's different because there is no any answer specific to this question.

Comment: Probably because you're exporting CSV or HTML and calling it Excel. Show the code that generates the document.

Comment: Please see my post, i have mention the code which I am using.

Comment: No, that is not the code which is generating the Excel file.

Comment: @model string

@{
    Layout = null;
    Response.Clear();
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Survey Report.xlsx");
}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<ss:Workbook xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet">
    <ss:Styles>
        <ss:Style ss:ID="1">
            <ss:Font ss:Bold="1"/>
    ......................

Comment: @CodeCaster Hope you have some idea on MVC?